# How can I estimate CO2 emissions for a vehicle travel distance

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

How can I properly estimate CO2 emissions for a given travel distance (of a private vehicle)?

I found the following formula, but I'm not sure that it's correct:

```
kgCO2 = Average fuel consumption per 100 km * kgCO2 per liter of fuel * travel distance / 100 km
```

For example, if a vehicle consumes around 5 l/km, traveling distance is 35km and this is a diesel vehicle, then the result would be:

```
5 * 2.9 * 35 / 100 = 5.075 kgCO2
```

(I don't know if 2.9 if a correct value of kgCO2 per liter of diesel).

Moreover, I want to consider a vehicle occupancy factor (for instance, 1 passenger would refer to 25%, 2 passengers would refer to 50%, etc.) that also somehow impacts CO2 emissions.

Of course, many other factors (e.g. car production year) might be additionally considered. However, I'm searching for a relatively simple (though quite accurate) formula that would take into account fuel type (diesel, petrol, gas), vehicle occupancy factor, travel distance and average fuel consumption per 100km.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Physics SE.  Feel free to look around, and take the Tour (under 'help' on the top menu bar).  'Relatively simple' and 'quite accurate' for this problem would seem to be highly contradictory here. If you own a car, what is your experience with km/l as a factor of those variables? I'll note you didn't include speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The carbon dioxide panic is so widespread that these days, virtually all carmakers make the data available for the CO2 emissions per kilometer directly. For example, this is the table for all Škoda models

> https://www.fleetnews.co.uk/cars/co2-emissions-calculator/skoda/

Replace "skoda" in the URL by "audi" or another brand to get the numbers you're interested in. New passenger cars generally emit from 90 (smaller cars) to 150 (larger cars) grams of CO2 (yes, it's the weight of the whole carbon dioxide, not just the carbon in it) per kilometer.

I hope that it's clear that if you need to know the CO2 emissions per 5 or 100 kilometers, you multiply the CO2 emissions per kilometer by 5 or by 100.

These numbers are measured under the same conditions as the "fuel consumption". If the fuel consumption goes up (or down), because of a higher (lower) number of passengers or another reason, the CO2 emissions go up (down) by pretty much the same coefficient.

The CO2 emissions per kilometer aren't too strongly affected by the number of the human passengers. They're much lighter than the car. These emissions per kilometer may be rather accurately calculated from the fuel consumption per kilometer times a "universal factor" encoding how much CO2 a liter of petrol or diesel emits to the air.

The relevant numbers are e.g. in the first table here:

> http://people.exeter.ac.uk/TWDavies/energy_conversion/Calculation%20of%20CO2%20emissions%20from%20fuels.htm

1 liter of petrol and diesel creates 2.31 or 2.68 kilograms of CO2 emissions, respectively. Newly produced cars allow you to go up to 20 kilometers or so for a liter (i.e. 5 liters per 100 kilometers) which agrees with the figure of 100+ grams of CO2 emissions per kilometer (2 kg per 20 km).